# Mobile Data/Cellular Internet Connected but No Internet Package NetInfo return true

Tags: android, ios, react-native

When mobile phone device is connected via **cellular internet** (i.e: Edge, 3G, WiMax, or LTE) but there is **no internet package** / **no Credit in sim**  , Netinfo isConnected always **return true** for both iOS & Android. How to resolve it.

```
  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
     alert(isConnected);
   })
```